# React Bootstrap fullscreen prop not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

### Describe the bug

Adding the fullscreen prop to Modal isn't making the Modal go fullscreen.

### Reproducible Example

Minimal example by using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-panka-9ep6b?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675).

### Expected behavior

The modal to be fullscreen.

### Screenshots

This is the example on Code Sandbox. It's also not working on my app. In my app I'm using the latest version of the react-bootstrap package. The Code Sandbox example is using 1.5.2.
[image: Screen Shot 2021-09-22 at 10 20 28 AM]

### Environment

- Operating System: macOS M1
- Browser, Version: Chrome v94
- React-Bootstrap Version: 1.5.2 on Code Sandbox. 1.6.3 in my app.

### Additional context

I'm confused because the fullscreen prop seems to be working in the example in the docs. You can run a phone emulator in Chrome [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modal-fullscreen) and see it working.
I don't see any important difference between the code in my app and the docs. Am I missing something? Doing something wrong?
Lastly, I am trying to affect only one particular modal in my app, and I only want the modal to go fullscreen when the screen size is small.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the fullscreen prop on a Bootstrap Modal is only compatible with react-bootstrap version 5. Someone kindly helped me out on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/6054).

To upgrade to Bootstrap 5, run these commands in your terminal:

1. `npm uninstall bootstrap`
2. `npm uninstall react-bootstrap`
3. `npm install react-bootstrap@next bootstrap@5.1.1`
4. Put the following snippet in your index.html file, in your public folder

```
<link
 rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU"
 crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

If you don't have Bootstrap already installed then the first two commands won't be necessary.

Note: If your app is using Bootstrap 4, it may not be worth upgrading to Bootstrap 5 just for this prop. There are at least several Bootstrap 4 React components that aren't compatible with Bootstrap 5, (i.e. Form.File, Accordion.Toggle, and InputGroup.Prepend).

Answer (score 0):

you must remove padding of container

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-panka-9ep6b?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

Answer (score 0):

add this style to your modal-dialog :

```
style="max-width: 100% !important; max-height: 100% !important;"
```

Comment: @Ashkam Khaleghi can you show an example? I only want the fullscreen prop to affect one particular modal, and only when the screen size is small. Changing the modal-dialog class, from what I understand, will change all modals.

Comment: in your particular Modal tag add this style

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working for me either. In fact, it produces an error in the console and doesn't seem to be compatible with JSX.